# Scroll só funciona em uma div

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Astro</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="screen" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="membros" style="overflow: auto;">
            <div class="metade1" style="height: 100%; width: 50%; position: fixed; z-index: 1; top: 0; overflow-x: hidden; padding-top: 50px; left: 0; padding: 50px; background-color: black;">
                <div id="avatares" style="float: left;">
                    <div id="such" style="">
                        <img style=" border-radius: 50%; padding: 1px; border: 4px solid transparent; background: white; margin-bottom: 20px;"
                        src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/740398084714135553/a_fd6c86a5108333255ccc248146708f9c.gif"
                    </div>
                    <div id="proud">
                        <img style="border-radius: 50%; padding: 1px; border: 4px solid transparent; background: white; margin-bottom: 20px; " src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/333388427053629441/03ca5ec0fbdb49a8d668bbe87364bd32.png"
                    </div>
                    <div id="magic">
                        <img style="border-radius: 50%; padding: 1px; border: 4px solid transparent; background: white; margin-bottom: 20px;" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/741857364113620992/a_c4ccd223f9d3ae8d7d49b51598a2225a.gif"
                    </div>
                    <div id="kettles">
                        <img style="border-radius: 50%; padding: 1px; border: 4px solid transparent; background: white; margin-bottom: 20px;" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/325275170572992514/a_9be814a7e2dd530f6c5004b5a8e7855e.gif"
                    </div>
                    <div id="kyo">
                        <img style="border-radius: 50%; padding: 1px; border: 4px solid transparent; background: white; margin-bottom: 20px;" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/287315272208089088/a_3005f36b83ccc267b66d1863b756d409.gif"
                    </div>
                    <div id="crumble">
                        <img style=" border-radius: 50%; padding: 1px; border: 4px solid transparent; background: white; margin-bottom: 20px;" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/739833577402925138/01138aa44ebeb4fd09a1d2343b45f13d.png"
                    </div>
                    <div id="hozz">
                        <img style="border-radius: 50%; padding: 1px; border: 4px solid transparent; background: white; margin-bottom: 20px;" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/721548699573944390/75abab6793c82fdfef9eecedf0af468a.png"
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="metade2" style="height: 100%; width: 50%; position: fixed; z-index: 1; top: 0; overflow-x: hidden; padding-top: 50px; right: 0; padding: 50px; background-color: black;">
            <div class="avatares" style="float: right;">
                <div id="fiuza">
                    <img style="border-radius: 50%; padding: 1px; border: 4px solid transparent; background: white; margin-bottom: 20px;" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/420246215255654440/3aa25dd3e96e952db3cf5de4c0a6c580.png"
                </div>

                <div id="lord">
                    <img style="border-radius: 50%; padding: 1px; border: 4px solid transparent; background: white; margin-bottom: 20px;;" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/405415563834294272/156822b1b766b74e86c790e154383cff.png"
                </div>

                <div id="velvet">
                    <img style="border-radius: 50%; padding: 1px; border: 4px solid transparent; background: white; margin-bottom: 20px;" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/521405803383750658/d5db362ccedd3fa43c75450c1970756d.png"
                </div>

                <div id="jota">
                    <img style="border-radius: 50%; padding: 1px; border: 4px solid transparent; background: white; margin-bottom: 20px;" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/585135809967947881/b81c2304764cee530f2ee591a3d730ce.png"
                </div>

                <div id="guxx">
                    <img style="border-radius: 50%; padding: 1px; border: 4px solid transparent; background: white; margin-bottom: 20px;" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/786235501694812190/a_acacd71fe0ff1da18d65d1841fcd5534.gif"
                </div>

                <div id="yuki">
                    <img style="border-radius: 50%; padding: 1px; border: 4px solid transparent; background: white; margin-bottom: 20px;" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/762851689480454154/0bb12d547d6d100cea426ab62da27773.png"
                </div>

                <div id="res">
                    <img style="border-radius: 50%; padding: 1px; border: 4px solid transparent; background: white; margin-bottom: 20px;" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/739928423199277149/a_afbaf6ac3521d10d6521423bb4f875f2.gif"
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Estou começando em front-end, e basicamente, a scroll só desce na parte direita, ou seja, na `div metade2`.

Answer (score 2):

Olá, encontrei alguns pontos para corrigir esse problema.

1 - As tags img, precisam ser fechadas dessa forma, esta faltando o fechamento da tag />.

2 - Ambas as divs estão com width: 50%, porém quando você acrescenta um padding de 50px em cada div, então elas na verdade não terão apenas os 50% e sim 50% mais 50px em cada lado, também acima e abaixo.

O motivo do srcroll não ir até o final é que o padding está fazendo com que a altura da div seja maior que o scroll. para resolver isso adicione em ambas as divs metade1 e metade2 a propriedade: **box-sizing: border-box;**

Isso fará com que as divs respeitem a largura e altura que você define para a div sem aumentar os tamanhos delas.

Vocẽ pode ver mais sobre isso aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing